# Twitter API: search for geotagged media

Tags: java, twitter

Recently, Twitter announced the discontinuation of tweet geotagging: https://twitter.com/twittersupport/status/1141039841993355264?lang=en

However, you can still "tag your precise location in Tweets through our updated camera." Concerning Twitter API, how would I search/filter for tweets with geotagged photos? I've asked Twitter Support, but they haven't responded in 2 weeks.
I have a premium developer account and use the full archive database for searches.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Photos are never geotagged in Twitter, only Tweets are. You'd need to search for Tweets with location info, that have media attached. The premium search operators should enable this.

Comment: @Andy Piper So when someone uses the camera feature in the Twitter app, is geolocation information is stored in the tweet or the actual photo?

Comment: The Tweet. All geo data is always removed from any images.

Comment: @Andy Piper What if you wanted to get back all the images from a specific event? A sporting event for example - say the 2019 woman's world cup final in paris? Or the men's world cup 2018 final in moscow? If you search by bounding box and date you only get a couple hundred tweets. Filtering by "filter:images" further reduces the count to a couple dozen tweets. In reality, I imagine there are thousands of tweets with hundreds of images. Is there really no way to search for these images geospatially?

Comment: It is down to user choice as to whether the Tweets are geotagged. Historically, very few users geotagged their Tweets. I'm not surprised if there are small numbers of results from such a search. Twitter does not proactively add geo data to Tweets when users have not chosen to do so,